# При компиляции TON не видит block-auto.cpp(его там нету)

Tags: telegram, cmake

```bsh
cmake .../TON/lite-client
```

В конце ошибка

```bsh
CMake Error at .../TON/lite-client/crypto/CMakeLists.txt:272 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    .../TON/lite-client/crypto/block/block-auto.cpp
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос? Очевидно, ваша проблема в том, что файла нет :)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb так меня собственно и интересует, почему этот файл там отсутствует)